# How to merge out parameter nested tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image]

I have two procedures. When second procedure is being called by Procedure 1, it returns a table as an out parameter. Sometimes Procedure 2 may be called more than one time. The question is how can I merge (or append) everything I got from procedure 2 into one table?

Table type is user -defined:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_record AS OBJECT
(
  i         NUMBER,
  city_name VARCHAR2(100)
);

create or replace type t_table as table of t_record;
```

I know about `MULTISET UNION ALL`, but it seems impossible to use it since I don't know how many times Procedure 2 will be called within Procedure 1.

What should I do? Maybe everything I do is wrong and there's a better way to do it. I will be glad to hear any suggestions.

FOR @hotfix

I have simplified the code of the Procedure 1. It actually calls Procedure 2 within the loop and after loop.

```
FOR insurance_program IN insurance_programs LOOP
    IF insurance_program.level_of_service = 'additional' THEN
        Procedure2(client_id, 2, insurance_program.program_id, avaliable_cities);
    END IF; 
END LOOP; 

Procedure2(client_id, 1, 1, avaliable_cities);
```

Comment: Show us a code how do you call procedure 2? is it a Loop?

Comment: @hotfix It's a cursor for loop. Procedure 2 is called when conditions are met. I would show the code, but there's NDA, you know.

Comment: you do not Need to post your original code, you can just add a simple example how you do it in your code, to understand  it

Comment: Can't you just copy them over using a `insert into` into the 'procedure 1' output table?

Comment: @Caramiriel type table is an Array not a table, you can't user insert for it

Comment: @hotfix I have added some code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MULTISET UNION ALL` to append it to the array you are returning:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure1(
  client_id        IN  NUMBER,
  available_cities OUT t_table
)
IS
  program_available_cities t_table;

  -- Dummy cursor with 3 rows.
  CURSOR insurance_programs IS
    SELECT LEVEL AS program_id,
           'additional' AS level_of_service
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
BEGIN
  available_cities := t_table();

  FOR insurance_program IN insurance_programs LOOP
    IF insurance_program.level_of_service = 'additional' THEN
      Procedure2( client_id, 2, insurance_program.program_id, program_available_cities );
      available_cities := available_cities MULTISET UNION ALL program_available_cities;
    END IF; 
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Example**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_record AS OBJECT
(
  i         NUMBER,
  city_name VARCHAR2(100)
);

create or replace type t_table as table of t_record;

-- Dummy procedure to output 4 cities every time it is called
CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure2(
  client_id  IN NUMBER,
  variable1  IN NUMBER,
  program_id IN NUMBER,
  available_cities OUT t_table
)
IS
BEGIN
  available_cities := t_table();
  available_cities.EXTEND(4);
  FOR i IN 1 .. 4 LOOP

    available_cities(i) := t_record(
                             4 * program_id + i - 4,
                             'City' || TO_CHAR( 4 * program_id + i - 4 )
                           );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

DECLARE
  available_cities t_table;
BEGIN
  Procedure1( 1, available_cities );
  FOR i in 1 .. available_cities.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( available_cities(i).i || ': ' || available_cities(i).city_name );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
1: City1
2: City2
3: City3
4: City4
5: City5
6: City6
7: City7
8: City8
9: City9
10: City10
11: City11
12: City12
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=968f3a3e4174d9c596e55e254557fd37)*